# search for none case sensitive in dataset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
dataset = dataset.where(:headline.like("%" + headline + "%")) if headline.present?
```

I have a search form where i can search for headlines. But the headline search is case sensitive :S. This is the comparison oh the headline and the headline in the dataset. Thought like wasnt case sensitive :S Is ther somethin else that is not case sensitive?

Comment: If I could just cast both the searchphrase and the matching symbol to downcase, then problem would be solved right?

I tried doing this by setting (:headline.downcase).like and headline.downcase. But that didn't work, as you can't invoke 'like' on a Symbol. Any Idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. 
Apparently there's a method ilike, that works the same way as 'like' but that is case insensitive.
For some weird reason it's not on APIdock, but trust me, it works. ( http://apidock.com/rails/search?query=ilike )

Answer (score 2):

Simple. You can use the SQL lower function and use the downcase Ruby String method :

```
@posts = Post.where("lower(name) like ?", "%#{search.downcase}%")
```

This will make your search case insensitive and that works with many RDBMS.